# Is it possible to use Kendo UI FX with MVVM binding?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I'm currently using two-way binding to control the visibility of a DIV based on a boolean in my view model. Instead of merely setting it as visible or hidden, I would like it to expand or contract via the the "expand" effect.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/effects/expand

I don't see any way to bind this via MVVM. Has anyone managed to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for use kendo effects? why not handle via events with jQuery effects?

Comment: Our front-end uses Kendo UI MVVM view binding, which is declarative and binds off of a JS view model. The goal is to elegantly integrate it with Kendo FX. If we are willing to step outside of the declarative binding MVVM approach, then we could use anything, including jQuery effects.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the given link from where I got help for my issue.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/custom